# Disabling scrollViewDidScroll method when searching in UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I implemented `scrollViewDidScroll` in order to update `UITableView` when tableView did scroll to bottom. and adding 10 new elements to it.
 
There is a `UISearchbar` in `UITableView` too. when I search something, scrolling might be needed. but I don't want `scrollViewDidScroll` to be executed in this situation.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let height = scrollView.frame.size.height
        let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
        if distanceFromBottom < height {
            print(" you reached end of the table")
            self.fetchOffset += 10
            // changing fillteredPosts. updating tableView.
        }
    }

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredPosts.removeAll()
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
        if let searchString = searchText, let searchInt = Int(searchString) {
            for post in originalAllPosts {
                if post.userId == searchInt {
                    filteredPosts.append(post)
                }
            }
        } 
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: tableview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Comment: @teixeiras Thanks. but I dont want to disable scrolling. It might be needed. I want to disable scrollViewDidScroll. search result could be more than a page, so scrolling is needed.

Comment: So you want to disable the callback to delegate, or, you must make an if around  the scrollViewDidScroll content using an property seated on search begin, you also could try to set the scrollview delegate inside the tableview to nil during the search and put it back on the search end. This last one I never tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are performing search for every single character that is entered

```
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if searchController.searchBar.text.isEmpty {
            let height = scrollView.frame.size.height
            let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
            if distanceFromBottom < height {
                print(" you reached end of the table")
                self.fetchOffset += 10
                // changing fillteredPosts. updating tableView.
            }
         }

    }
```

Here the statements inside `scrollViewDidScroll` will be executed only when searchBar is empty that means we are not performing a search action